# Getting positive definite matrix for chol update

Tags: matlab, matrix-decomposition

I am making a square-root UKF implementation. I also use `cholupdate` function in Matlab. However `cholupdate` needs a positive definite matrix. The positive definiteness is tested using `[R,p] = chol(A)` where `p` produces `0`. Then after running `cholupdate`, generates an error saying `A` is not positive definite. My problem is.

1. Does `[R,p] = chol(A)` return `p=0` means `A` is positive-definite always?
2. What is the best method for making a positive definite matrix. Note that here `A` is a square-root matrix where $AA^T$ gives a covariance matrix.

Comment: the documentation (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chol.html) indicates that `p=0` means `A` is positive definite. For your second question, note that a Gram matrix ($AA^{\top}$) is positive semidefinite, and you can always 'boost' the eigenvalues of any matrix by adding $cI$ to it; for sufficiently large $c$, $cI+A$ will be positive definite.

Comment: to obtain a positive definite matrix A_hat, you can compute the eigen decomposition of A, set the negative eigenvalues to zero, and recompose: B = (A+A')/2, [V,D] = eig(B), A_hat = V*max(D,0)*V'